# Is it possible to create a google cloud datalab instance not using datalab-network?

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

Because the way we use GCP, it's not possible for me to create a datalab-network in my setup. So when I create a Datalab instances though "datalab create", I get an error (ERROR: ...Required 'compute.networks.create' permission for 'projects/xxxx').

Is it possible to setup datalab and use my own network? I have tried to set it up like suggested here (http://e-lin.github.io/wiki/jekyll/update/2016/12/13/Running-Google-Cloud-Datalab.html) but I am not sure this is officially supported. When I open my browser at localhost:8081 I get a ERR_CONNECTION_RESET, and when I log onto the Compute Engine VM I don't see anything listening to port 8080 (docker ps does not show anything running). Do we need to start docker explicitly in such a case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to run Datalab on a different network, but it is not supported.

The recommended solution to your problem is to ask a project owner to create the network for you. Specifically, they would run two commands:

```
gcloud compute networks create \
    --description 'Network for Datalab instances' \
    datalab-network
gcloud compute firewall-rules create \
    --allow 'tcp:22' \
    --network datalab-network \
    --description 'Allow SSH access to Datalab instances' \
    datalab-network-allow-ssh
```

... and then you will be able to run `datalab create ...`

If that is not tenable, then you can clone the Datalab source repository [here](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab), change the name of the network [here](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/blob/11c4d929e90cfdefdf889be3b8ffa6b7df7b483a/tools/cli/commands/create.py#L35), comment out the line of code [here](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/blob/11c4d929e90cfdefdf889be3b8ffa6b7df7b483a/tools/cli/commands/create.py#L505), and then run `tools/cli/datalab.py create ...`.

Note, however, that approach is neither recommended nor supported.